# How do I determine the Big O of a recursive algorithm that includes an optimization?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, big-o

I know that the regular recursive function for the fibonacci algorithm is O(2^n) because it calls itself twice for each subsequent call, doubling its cost. However, after adding what I've seen described as an optimization (a hashtable of solutions to the sequence), how do you determine how much it reduces the complexity if at all?

For example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    static Hashtable<Integer, Integer> numbers = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();

    public static int fibonacci(int n) {
        if(n == 0 || n == 1){
            return n;
        }else if(numbers.containsKey(n)){
            return numbers.get(n);
        }else {
            int result = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
            numbers.put(n, result);
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.close();
        System.out.println(fibonacci(n));
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. "I know that the regular recursive function for the fibonacci algorithm is O(n^2) " - it's not, it's O(2^n). 2. You never populate `numbers`. 3. once you've implemented a *real* memoization you'll calculate each number only once, so the running time for `n` will be O(n)

Comment: I made a typo, sorry

Comment: It's not 2^n either, but phi^n, where phi = (sqrt(5)+1)/2 = 1.618... is the golden ratio. Fibonacci(30) takes about 2 million step to compute naively, rather than a billion. (Technically it is O(2^n), but only in the same sense that it's O(2^2^n): big O is an upper bound.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is O(n). What you have implemented is what's called memoization. What this really means is that when breaking problem in two (or general more) subproblems which are partly-overlapping  (e.g `F(5) = F(4) + F(3)`) ,both will need to compute F(2) so they overlap) when a value is computed it is stored so next time needed it will be already computed.

This means that in order to compute `F(n)` you will recursively compute all `F(i) ,i<n` and if some `F(i)` is more than once needed it will be computed only one time and will be available in `O(1)` (due o hashtable).So overall will be `O(n)`.

This is very similar to the dynamic algorithm version (with the small difference that instead of building the solutions e.g F(0),F(1),F(2) ...F(n) you do it backwards keeping track of what you have computed (memoization) ). Though I haven't checked if you're memoization algorithm has any bug... just explaining the concept and complexity of memoization algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the complexity of this function is Theta(2^n):

```
Fibonacci(n) {
    if (n < 0) return 0;
    if (n < 2) return 1;
    return Fibonacci(n - 1) + Fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

We can prove this by induction. Base case: for `n = 0` and `n = 1`, `0.5 * 2^n <= Fibonacci(n) = 1 <= 2 * 2^n`. Induction hypothesis: assume this holds for `n` up to and including `k`. Induction step: show that `0.5 * 2^(k+1) <= Fibonacci(k+1) <= 2 * 2^(k+1)`. Substituting, we get `0.5 * 2^(k+1) = 2*2^(k-1) <= 2*Fibonacci(k-1) <= Fibonacci(k) + Fibonacci(k-1) <= 2*Fibonacci(k) <= 2 * 2^k <= 2 * 2^(k+1)`. This completes the proof.

The hashtable of solutions (sometimes called a *memo*, whence *memoization*) prevents `Fibonacci(k)` from being invoked more than once per `k`. Since `Fibonacci(n)` only depends on `Fibonacci(0)`, `Fibonacci(1)`, ..., `Fibonacci(n-1)`, and since the hashtable and check prevents any of these from being called more than once, each is called exactly once, and since each does a constant amount of work for any given `n`, the total amount of work is `O(n)`. The recurrence relation is harder to think about now (we have side effects and need conditionals) so I have to avail myself of this sort of "trick" argument. Unfortunately, most proofs require some kind of "trick", induction being something of an exception.